# A general relativity question about 4-velocity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

In a general spacetime with metric $g_{\alpha\beta}$ where there exists  coordinates such that there are observers with 4-velocity $u^{\mu} = \{1,0,0,0\}$, show that 
$$
g_{00} = -1 \qquad\text{and}\qquad u_{\alpha} = g_{0\alpha}
$$
with $u_{0} = -1$ and $u_{i} = g_{0i}$. Use the fact that $u_{\alpha}u^{\alpha}= g_{\alpha\beta}u^{\alpha}u^{\beta} = -1$.

Could I please get a hint on how to start?

Comment: Strange question, but in any case, why can't you make the calculations explicitly? e.g. $u^0 u^0 = 1 \Rightarrow ??$

Answer (score 1):

Just write out the product

$$u_\alpha u^\alpha = g_{\alpha\beta}u^\alpha u^\beta= g_{00}u^0 u^0\ ,$$

since $u^i=0\ ,\ i=\{1,2,3\}$. Then imposing

$$u_\alpha u^\alpha = -1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad g_{00}=-1 \ .$$

I think the rest you can do on your own :)